# Re-enable the multiple tabs close warning in Firefox 50+

Tags: firefox

[image: image description]

I did some googling and apparently every time someone makes article that describes how to re-enable this warning, Firefox developers make it even harder - judging from the fact that newer articles on this topic were much longer and the newest already require you to dig in `about:config`.

Latest article I found is this one: http://warnmewhenclosingmultipletabs.blogspot.cz/

It didn't help, even though I set the settings correctly:

```
browser.tabs.warnOnQuit   true
browser.tabs.warnOnClose  true
```

The firefox still closes without confirmation dialog. That's annoying because I sometimes close it accidentally, eg. when trying to drag other window.

How to re-enable this dialog in the latest Firefox versions?

Comment: You need to say what OS you are using.

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox 57, it gets even worse. Unlike to what the existing answer says, there's no **"Warn me when closing multiple tabs"** option at all (see the arrow on the screenshot).

However, [setting](https://support.mozilla.org/uk/questions/1127960#answer-889512) the **"When Firefox starts"** option to "Home page" or "Blank page" (**not** "Tabs from last time" !) makes Firefox ask for confirmation before the exit.
As far as I understand the Mozilla's logic, there is no harm of closing the FF if all tabs get restored on next startup. They don't consider the possibility of failure to save the tabs (like it happened to me twice during the last 3 days).

[image: screenshot Firefox 57]

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Tools -> Options -> General -> Warn me when closing ...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> If you want to be prompted when multiple tabs are open there are two
>   settings required here as there are two methods of closing :
>   1)
>   Using the close button
>   2) File > Quit

To enable a warning for Method 1 ,  you need to set

```
browser.tabs.warnOnClose     true
```

To enable a warning for Method 2 , you need to set

```
 browser.warnOnQuit          true
 browser.showQuitWarning     true
```